# update array without object using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

if I have an array of object like this

`[{name: 'james', name: 'john'}]` and I know the index of john and want to change the value of john I'll do

`person = person.map((p, i)=>i===index?({...p, name: 'changed john'})):p)`
`this.setState({person})`

but what if the array is like this?
`['james', 'john']`

Comment: If you know the index of an item in an array, you don't need `map`, you just do `person[index] = ...`.

Comment: if you have `const arr = ['james','john']`, then you just do `arr[0] = 'Sam'` and then you'll have `['Sam','john']` ... You don't need to map. Just use array indexes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: If the values of items in the array are not directly changeable by array index then our answers won't work. This is more of a React state management issue than an array one isn't it? In that case, Nguyễn Thanh Tú answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

> but what if the array is like this? ['james', 'john']

Because the correct way to update state is using `setState` method, hence, the act of directly mutating state like `this.state.list[i]="Changed John"` won't work. I think that we just use `Array.prototype.map()` as usual. Like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: ['james', 'john']
    };
  }
  handleDelete = i => {
    const newList = this.state.list.filter((li, idx) => idx !== i);
    this.setState({ list: newList });
  };
  handleChange = i => {
    const newList = this.state.list.map(
      (li, idx) => (idx === i ? 'Changed ' + li : li)
    );
    this.setState({ list: newList });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map((e, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <p>{e}</p>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(i)}>Delete</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleChange(i)}>Change</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

---

Comment: map won't work if you have onChange on an input, where e.target.value is per character entered by the user.

Comment: @Melissa94 now then we see the `input` and `onChange`, the question should be updated cuz my answer doesn't intend to solve that

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```js
person = person.map((p, i) => p === "john" ? "changed john" : p);
```

Comment: You might need to get index.
`let index = person.indexOf("john")`
`person = person.map((p, i) => i=== index ? "changed john" : p);`

Answer (score 0):

***It's pretty easy. Here you have examples for both situations:***

```js
const test = [{name: 'james', name: 'john'}];

// Here we're accessing the 1st element and its 'name' property
console.log(test[0].name);
```

```js
// Here we're accessing the 2nd element.
// JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0

const test2 = ['james', 'john'];

console.log(test2[1])
```

I suggest visiting **MDN** [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for exploring other (all) examples.

Answer (score 0):

person = person.map((p, i) => p === "john" ? "changed john" : p);